# Filter products not working correctly with where query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, I have code:

```
public function attribute()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductAttribute');
}

public function scopeAttrSearch($query, $ids)
{
   foreach ($ids as $id) {
       $query->whereHas('attribute', function ($q) use ($id) {
           $q->where('attribute_value_id', $id);
       });
}

  return $query;
}
```

In ids I send values_attributes_id from database. I have list checkboxes with name the attribute_value. If has list of checkboxes when is selected products are filtered rigth by criteria. but if I select checkboses from same category, filter not normaly filetered, seems to conditional "where" not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass directly the incoming array to whereIn method.

```
public function scopeAttrSearch($query, $ids)
{
   $query->whereHas('attribute', function ($q) use ($ids) {
       $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $ids);
   });
   return $query;
}
```

Comment: but then filter not working with various filter categories.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach doesn't work with query, you can simplify the code:

```
public function scopeAttrSearch($query, $ids)
{
   return $query->whereHas('attribute', function ($q) use ($ids) {
       $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $ids);
   });
}
```

Comment: but then filter not working with various filter categories.

Comment: The various filters categories are records in attribute right?
So when you pass `$q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $ids);` $ids should contain an array of attribute_value_id's.

Comment: But I have and attribute_id, and attribute_id - category of filter. And when I check something from this. I not get products from this filters, I get all products..